# Is there any way to invert the layout of posts after each iteration wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, css

I have added posts on a section of a page in which I have written a query to display only two latest posts with their thumbnail on one side and text parallel to the thumbnail, what I want to do is that after each iteration I want the display to invert i.e: on first iteration thumbnail would be on right side and text on left while in the next iteration I want the thumbnail to be on left and text on right.

Here is my code for posts:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2 class="main-hadding">our blog news</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-section">
        <div class="row"> 

    <?php
//display 2 posts for category id 47
    $args=array(
    //  'cat' => 47,
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 2,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1
      );
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
          $Post_ID = get_the_ID ();


      ?>

<!--        Post Thumbnail-->
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> 
              <?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
} 
     ?>     
        </div> 

<!--        Post Title and Content-->
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class=" blog-contant">
                <h1> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
            </div>
        </div>

       <?php
      endwhile;
    }
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
      </div>


 </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center btn-more"> <a href="#!" class="">MORE BLOG NEWS</a> </div>

</div>
```

Comment: well on your loop you can add a counter or condition in there... and add a separate view for the 2.

Comment: can you elaborate it please as i have searched for it but couldn't;t found anything useful

Answer (score 0):

A long and dirty solution, but this will work.. :D

```
$count = 0;
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : 
    $my_query->the_post(); 
    $Post_ID = get_the_ID ();
    if($count == 0) : ?>
        <!--Post Thumbnail-->
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> 
            <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                } 
            ?>     
        </div> 

        <!--Post Title and Content-->
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class=" blog-contant">
                <h1> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>

        <!--Post Title and Content-->
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class=" blog-contant">
                <h1> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Post Thumbnail-->
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> 
            <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                } 
            ?>     
        </div> 
    <?php
   endif;
   $count++;
endwhile;
```